# Jersey encoded query param but rest service doesn't want it encoded

Tags: java, rest, oauth-2.0, jersey, onedrive

I am trying to make a rest request to microsoft but some of the query parameters that I need to use are being encoded by jersey which results in them being wrong when interpreted by the rest service.

For example,

```
static String authorizationcode = "M2a34718e-5a3e-f8a1-4edb-d55adaf9aac9&lc=1033";
```

If this authorization code is encoded then the rest call fails.   Here is my code.  I didn't see any obvious way to get around this problem.  The client secret is also problematic as it can contain a space which seems to be encoded to a "+" before being sent across.

```
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(OneDriveEnum.OAUTH20_TOKEN_URL.toString());
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();

    queryParams.add(API_PARAM_CLIENT_ID, principal.getClientId());
    queryParams.add(API_PARAM_CLIENT_SECRET, principal.getClientSecret());
    queryParams.add(API_PARAM_CODE, principal.getAuthorizationCode());
    queryParams.add(API_PARAM_REDIRECT_URI, OneDriveEnum.OAUTH20_DESKTOP_REDIRECT_URL.toString());
    queryParams.add(API_PARAM_GRANT_TYPE, OneDriveEnum.GRANT_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION_CODE.toString());

    Builder b = webResource.queryParams(queryParams).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    ClientResponse clientResponse = b.get(ClientResponse.class);
```

Thanks for any thoughts !

Comment: I'm not familiar with any Microsoft service you're using but are you sure the authz code supposed to contain the `&lc=1033`.  You are using using the OAuth2.0 authz code grant, and the url from the redirect contains query parameters. Each key value pair is separated by a `&`. So the query string might look like `code=theAuthzCode&lc=1033`. Here `lc=1033` is separate key value parameter. It is not part of the code. The code is `theAuthzCode`. Try dropping the `&lc=1033` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah as you point out, it was the extra parameter in the parameter value that was causing the problem.  Thanks!